# Caffe loss starts off at 0 and stays at 0

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence, caffe, conv-neural-network

I am working on a small CNN defined here: http://pastebin.com/QHSxwrsT

[image]

When I start off the learning process, it tells me that the loss is 0 and throughout the iterations it stays at 0.

Is there a way to solve this?

Here is my solver:

```
net: "Convnet/modele_CNN.prototxt"
test_iter: 100
test_interval: 100
base_lr: 0.000000001
lr_policy: "step"
gamma: 0.1
stepsize: 10
display: 1
max_iter: 450000
momentum: 0.9
weight_decay: 0.0005
snapshot: 100
snapshot_prefix: "Convnet/Feature_detect_train"
solver_mode: GPU
```

... and the training prototxt file:

```
# CNN to create a probability map for the features
# Author: A. AYDIN (with very heavy contributions from C. Wolf)
# Date: 21/06/2016 

name: "Feature_detection"

# These are for training
# This layer extracts the images
layer 
{
    name: "ImageData"
    type: "Data"
    top: "data"
    top: "redundant1"
    include
    {
    phase: TRAIN
    }
    data_param
    {
        source: "Convnet/lmdbImageTrain"
        batch_size: 1
    backend: LMDB
    }
}

# This one extracts the labels (which are images)
layer
{
    name: "ImageGT"
    type: "Data"
    top: "label"
    top: "redundant2"
    include
    {
    phase: TRAIN
    }
    data_param
    {
        source: "Convnet/lmdbLabelTrain"
        batch_size: 1
    backend: LMDB
    }
}

# These are for validation
# This layer extracts the images
layer 
{
    name: "ImageData"
    type: "Data"
    top: "data"
    top: "redundant1"    
    include
    {
    phase: TEST
    }
    data_param
    {
        source: "Convnet/lmdbImageTest"
        batch_size: 1
    backend: LMDB
    }
}

# This one extracts the labels (which are images)
layer
{
    name: "ImageGT"
    type: "Data"
    top: "label"
    top: "redundant2"
    include
    {
    phase: TEST
    }
    data_param
    {
        source: "Convnet/lmdbLabelTest"
        batch_size: 1
    backend: LMDB
    }
}

# We are going to have 2 Conv+Norm+MaxPool layers 
layer
{
    name:"Conv5x5x32"
    type:"Convolution"
    bottom: "data"
    top: "conv1"
    convolution_param
    {
        kernel_size: 5 
        num_output: 32
        # The filters are 5x5x32
        pad: 2  
        # So the output is HxWx32 
    }
}

layer
{
    name: "Norm1"
    type: "LRN"
    bottom: "conv1"
    top: "norm1"
    lrn_param
    {
        # For now, I am using the default variables of:
        # local_size: 5
        # alpha: 1
        # beta: 5
        norm_region: WITHIN_CHANNEL 
    }
}

layer
{
    name: "Pool1"
    type: "Pooling"
    bottom: "norm1"
    top: "pool1"
    pooling_param
    {
        pool: MAX
        kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
    }   
}
# The first one is done, now onto the second

layer
{
    name:"Conv3x3x64_1"
    type:"Convolution"
    bottom: "pool1"
    top: "conv2"
    convolution_param
    {
        kernel_size: 3
        num_output: 64
        # The filters are 3x3x64
        pad: 1  
        # So the output is H/2xW/2x64 
    }
}

layer
{
    name: "Norm2"
    type: "LRN"
    bottom: "conv2"
    top: "norm2"
    lrn_param
    {
        # For now, I am using the default variables of:
        # local_size: 5
        # alpha: 1
        # beta: 5
        norm_region: WITHIN_CHANNEL 
    }
}

layer
{
    name: "Pool2"
    type: "Pooling"
    bottom: "norm2"
    top: "pool2"
    pooling_param
    {
        pool: MAX
        kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
    }   
}

# Now that we are done with the Conv+Norm+Max, we will have 3 layers of conv3x3x64

layer
{
    name:"Conv3x3x64_2"
    type:"Convolution"
    bottom: "pool2"
    top: "conv3"
    convolution_param
    {
        kernel_size: 3
        num_output: 64
        # The filters are 3x3x64
        pad: 1  
        # So the output is H/4xW/4x64 
    }
}

layer
{
    name:"Conv3x3x64_3"
    type:"Convolution"
    bottom: "conv3"
    top: "conv4"
    convolution_param
    {
        kernel_size: 3
        num_output: 64
        # The filters are 3x3x64
        pad: 1  
        # So the output is H/4xW/4x64
    }
}

layer
{
    name:"Conv3x3x64_4"
    type:"Convolution"
    bottom: "conv4"
    top: "conv5"
    convolution_param
    {
        kernel_size: 3
        num_output: 64
        # The filters are 3x3x64
        pad: 1  
        # So the output is H/4xW/4x64
    }
}

# Followed by a layers of conv3x3x256
layer
{
    name:"Conv3x3x256"
    type:"Convolution"
    bottom: "conv5"
    top: "conv6"
    convolution_param
    {
        kernel_size: 3
        num_output: 256
        # The filters are 3x3x256
        pad: 1  
        # So the output is H/4xW/4x256 
    }
}
# And lastly, a with a conv3x3x1
layer
{
    name:"Conv3x3x1"
    type:"Convolution"
    bottom: "conv6"
    top: "conv7"
    convolution_param
    {
        kernel_size: 3
        num_output: 1
        # The filters are 3x3x64
        pad: 1  
        # So the output is H/4xW/4x1 
    }
}
# We transform the last feature map into a probability map
layer
{
    name: "Prob"
    type: "Softmax"
    bottom: "conv7"
    top: "prob"
}


# Lastly we calculate the loss
layer
{
    name:"Loss"
    type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
    bottom: "prob"
    bottom: "label"
    top: "loss"
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: What have you done to debug the problem?  If nothing else, insert some tracing print statements into the Caffe code to report some critical values.  Are you getting any input?  Do you get into the loss computation, or is it merely initialized to 0 and never changed?  If not, what input arguments are preventing the call from running properly?

Comment: To attempt to debug it, I tried to play on the learning rate. It did not help. I am currently using the terminal interface on a server so I can't really modify the code.

Comment: How many different label images do you have?  Does each input have its own output image?  It's possible to get this perfection problem with such a case.  Also, why is the batch size only 1?

Comment: I have a GT for each image. The batch size is 1 because if not the it gives me memory problems.

Comment: Okay ... what is a "GT"?  Golden Target?